# Style span inside ins and del tag

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<span class="price">
    <span class="amount floating">
         <del><span class="amount">275,00&nbsp;kr.</span></del> 
         <ins><span class="amount">149,00&nbsp;kr.</span></ins>
    </span>
</span>
```

Right now I have this css:

```
ul.products li.product .price ins {
    background: none;
    top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.amount.floating .amount:first-child {
    background-color:#000000;
}
.amount.floating .amount:first-child {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

I only want the first price (normal price) to be black... The other one (onsale) should be green.
Right now both are black.

**Note: As im working in a CMS, I would like a CSS solution**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want the final layout to look like, but when I created a fiddle from the code you provided there was an ugly mess. This seems to be caused in part due to `.amount.floating` with no space (in `.amount.floating .amount:first-child`).

To make the line green, just do this:

```
 ins .amount {
    color: green;
 }
```

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nd0z2o9u/2/)

Comment: try `ins .amount { color: green; }`

Comment: Solution was: .amount.floating ins span.amount {
  background-color: #98B827 !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
.amount.floating ins span { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       .amount.floating .amount:first-child {
        background-color:#000000;
        }

        .amount.floating ins span.amount {
         background-color: #98B827 !important;
         }
```

This was working